# Cx-Freeze : Showwarning AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, anaconda, cx-freeze

Scripts works fine on source file with using Anaconda alongside with Python 3.4. When i cxfreeze  (v 4.3.4) it with following setup file:

> from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
>
> setup(executables=[Executable("main.py", base="Win32GUI")],
> version='0.2')

I got following error on the server:

> DBOps.py", line 54, in executemany
>
> "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line
> 286, in executemany   File
>
> "FileC:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 127, in _warning_check   File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\warnings.py",
>
> line 15, in showwarning AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

I thougth different python versions installed on my system might result this problem, removed them by using installer. Nothing changed. Same error on both server and lochal machines. The errorneous part seems like "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\warnings.py", since there is no such directory path neither on my system or on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the relevant solution by Thomas Kluyver:

> The bigger issue there is that anything that attempts to show a
>   warning will cause an error, because by default it tries to write
>   warnings to sys.stderr, and if you use the Win32GUI base, there's no
>   stderr to write to. Calling warnings.simplefilter('ignore') beforehand
>   should prevent that.

source:https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/81/python-34-venv-importlib-attributeerror